# How to remove less frequent words from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How do i remove words that appears less than x time for example words appear less than 3 times in pandas dataframe. I use nltk as non english word removal, however the result is not good. I assume that word apear less than 3 times as non english words.

```
input_text=["this is th text one tctst","this is text two asdf","this text will be remove"]
def clean_non_english(text):
    text=" ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(text)if w.lower() in words or not w.isalpha())
    return text
Dataset['text']=Dataset['text'].apply(lambda x:clean_non_english(x))
```

Desired output

```
input_text=["this is text ","this is text ","this is text"]
```

so the word appear in the list less than 3 times will be removed

Comment: Without sample data or desired output I'm not sure If I understood your question, but what I found helpful while calculating word frequencies was `nltk.probability.freqdist`. something like `fdist = FreqDist(word.lower() for word in word_tokenize(sent))` should give you a dictionary with a separate word as a key, and its frequency as a value. from there you could filter your data accordingly.

Comment: I am sorry for unclear question, however i update my question, thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```py
input_text=["this is th text one tctst","this is text two asdf","this text will be remove"]
all_ = [x for y in input_text for x in y.split(' ') ]
a, b = np.unique(all_, return_counts = True)
to_remove = a[b < 3]
output_text = [' '.join(np.array(y.split(' '))[~np.isin(y.split(' '), to_remove)])
                for y in input_text]
```

Comment: I agree with your answer, though I see a typo `fiter` -> `filter`.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i am looking for

Comment: glad I've been of help ^^